# SwiftUI: problemas con el TextField

Tags: swift

[no-ios](/questions/tagged/no-ios)

Tal vez se pregunte por qué la interfaz de usuario se parece a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59754983/how-to-get-rid-of-the-blue-selection-border-around-swiftui-textfields). No soy el mismo tipo, solo soy otra persona que trabaja en el mismo proyecto. El autor de la pregunta vinculada me ha delegado para resolver el problema. Bueno, como se señaló, ¿cómo me deshago del borde de selección azul, y también cómo hago que el cursor tenga la altura correcta cuando el campo de texto está vacío? También hay problemas con errores al cambiar el tamaño de la ventana no puede actualizar el tamaño y la posición del texto hasta que haga clic en él.

Código:

```
TextField("World Name", text: self.$WorldName)
    .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/24))
    .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 6)
    .frame(width: geometry.size.width*0.75, height: geometry.size.width/20)
    .background(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
            .fill(Color.init(white: 0.28))
    )
TextField("World Seed", text: self.$WorldSeed)
    .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/24))
    .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 6)
    .frame(width: geometry.size.width*0.75, height: geometry.size.width/20)
    .background(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
            .fill(Color.init(white: 0.28))
    )
```

El cursor tiene la altura incorrecta cuando el campo está vacío:

[image]

[image]

Buggy se ve al cambiar el tamaño:

Ventana normal:

[image]

Se ve así cuando lo cambio de tamaño:

[image]

Pero tan pronto como hago clic en los campos, parece normal nuevamente:

[image]

Y finalmente, ¿cómo hago para que este borde de selección azul se ajuste de acuerdo con las esquinas redondeadas, el relleno, etc.? Si alguien sabe cómo resolverían mis problemas, se agradecerá una respuesta. Creo que he señalado cuatro problemas:

- El cambio de tamaño le da un aspecto defectuoso; ¿Cómo uso correctamente el GeometryReader para hacer que el tamaño de los campos de texto dependa del tamaño de la ventana?
- El borde azul debe ajustarse correctamente a cualquier relleno, esquinas redondeadas, etc.
- Cuando está vacío, el cursor tiene el tamaño incorrecto.
- Además, el borde azul no se desvanece con la animación, cambiando a otra pantalla, como también se indica en la pregunta vinculada.

Para aquellos que afirman que debería hacer estos cuatro problemas como preguntas separadas, no creo que sea necesario. Piense en esta pregunta como *¿Cómo puedo hacer un campo de texto personalizado sin errores, cuyo tamaño está determinado por GeometryReader?* Y estos problemas distintos son errores que necesito corregir para resolver este problema mayor.

Comment: las letras son muy grandes para el textField

Comment: @x-rw Entonces, ¿cómo hago para que el campo de texto acepte letras más grandes?

Comment: @JulianTiermann no deben ser muy grandes porque automaticamente aparecera un scroll, a menos que quieras un scroll deberias usar letras grandes en un textfield

Comment: @x-rw No hay evidencia de que aparezca un pergamino.

Comment: @JulianTiermann tambien debe ser porque estas usando un padding para el textField

Comment: @x-rw Sí, lo sé, y la pregunta es cómo hacer que el relleno actúe correctamente cuando se aplica a un campo de texto. Simplemente eliminarlo no es una solución.

Comment: puedes poner el codigo donde pones el cursor, porfavor

Comment: @x-rw Ya puse TODO el código para el campo de texto. El código para el cursor está en la biblioteca SwiftUI, no en ninguno de mis códigos

Answer (score 0):

Creo que una solucion seria utilizar letras mas pequeñas para que no se cree automaticamente un scroll dentro del textField

puedes disminuir el tamano de la letra asi:

```
tuTextField.font = UIFont(name: "nombre de la letra", size: 8.0)
```

pero si necesitas letras grandes debes agrandar tu textField:

```
tuTextField.bounds.height = 50
```

para corregir el cursor puedes usar el siguiente codigo:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                    tuTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
                }
```

Comment: Pero necesito saber cómo hacer que las letras no tengan errores cuando son grandes. Quiero letras grandes

Comment: También estoy usando SwiftUI y el código proporcionado no es SwiftUI.

Comment: @JulianTiemann corregi mi codigo, faltaba .bounds